# What makes a dir a project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

(Java 101 -- probably so simple a question that I can't find an answer because everyone assumes it's so obvious.)

I'm using eclipse. I went to open what I thought was a project. I did not realize that, in fact, it was a directory with several projects in it. As a result, eclipse iterated through and opened each of them as separate projects in my Package Explorer panel. That got me thinking: on what basis did eclipse decide that the root directory was NOT a project, and that the individual dirs within the root directory were projects?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for their answers so far, but I'd still like to have something clarified. OK -- if I create the project **in eclipse** then it will add a `.project` file (and other IDEs might add their own convention files), but what happens if I did not create a project in an IDE -- it's just dirs and plain source files; would eclipse (or any IDE) thereby be able to discern that a given dir is a 'project'?

Answer (score 2):

The presence of a valid `.project` file in a directory makes it an Eclipse project. If there is no `.project` file Eclipse will not recognise this as an Eclipse project.

Package/Project Explorer don't normal show files starting with '.' so you won't see these files unless you change the Explorer filter settings.

The `.project` is an XML file which contains the basic details about the Eclipse project. It contains things like the project 'nature' which says that it is a Java project or a Plug-in project or whatever.

The most basic `.project` for a 'general' project looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>General Project</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

A Java project looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Java Project</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

which adds the Java nature and the command for building Java code.

Different project types may add other '.' files. For example, a Java project will have a `.classpath` file containing the Java classpath settings.

Comment: Thanks -- please see my edit which asks for clarification: can an IDE discern that a dir is a project in the absence of any .project-like files?

Comment: If there is no .project file it is not an Eclipse project. This is a vital file and the dir will not be recognised without it. Other IDEs have different ways of doing things, there is no general answer.

Comment: What you can do is create a project and then import additional content from a plain directory.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to go one level deeper and set the root directory as an individual project within the original directory. The `.project` and `.classpath` files in a project are how Eclipse determines if a directory is a project.

Comment: Just `.project` is enough, `.classpath` is for Java projects - some non-Java projects won't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse actually creates invisible files containing metadata about the project

[image]